# Flutter FutureBuilder Does Not Wait When App Updates

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

**Problem** My FutureBuilder waits when app first runs but doesn't wait when app updates.

When my app finishes loading and I change to a different ToggleButton, the *FutureBuilder* starts to rerun immediately instead of waiting for *getData()* and it fully completes before *getData()* is finished and then when *getData()* is finally finished, *FutureBuilder* runs again.

This problem does not happen when the app first runs. When the app first runs, the *FutureBuilder* waits for *getData()* to complete before running.

I need *FutureBuilder* to wait for *getData()* to finish when a different button is pressed just like it does when the app first starts up.

Note: I removed as much unnecessary code as I could for readability. I can add more code if it will help.

Code:

```
class PriceScreenState extends State<PriceScreen> {
  String selectedCurrency = 'USD';
  String selectedGraphType = "1D";
      var isSelectedGraph = <bool>[true, false, false, false, false, false];

getData() async {
    isWaiting = true;
    try {
      Map graphData = await GraphData().getGraphData(
          selectedCurrency: selectedCurrency,
          selectedGraphType: selectedGraphType);
      isWaiting = false;
      setState(() {
        graphValues = graphData;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureData = getData();
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
...(other code)...
ToggleButtons( ****************TOGGLEBUTTONS***********
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                    child: Text('1D'),
                  ),
                 ...(more Buttons)...
                ],
                onPressed: (int index) {
                  setState(() {
                    for (int buttonIndex = 0;
                        buttonIndex < isSelectedGraph.length;
                        buttonIndex++) {
                      if (buttonIndex == index) {
                        isSelectedGraph[buttonIndex] = true;
                        selectedGraphType = graphType[buttonIndex];
                      } else {
                        isSelectedGraph[buttonIndex] = false;
                      }
                    }
                  });
                  getData();
                },
                isSelected: isSelectedGraph,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: FutureBuilder( *************FUTUREBUILDER*********
                    future: futureData,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (graphValues.isEmpty) {
                        return new Container();
                      } else {
                        return Graph(graphValues);
                      }
                    }),
              )
```

Comment: you are not using `snapshot` in any way, you have some examples in the official `FutureBuilder` docuemntation, just follow them

Comment: @pskink thank you I will check that out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using a `FutureBuilder` you don't need to call `setState` anymore. Here is a possible rework of your code:

```dart
Future<Map> futureData;

Future<Map> getData() async {
   try {
      Map graphData = await GraphData().getGraphData(
         selectedCurrency: selectedCurrency,
         selectedGraphType: selectedGraphType,
      );
      return graphData;
   } catch (e) {
      throw Exception(e);
   }
}

@override
void initState() {
   super.initState();
   futureData = getData();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   // Only coding the FutureBuilder for the example
   return FutureBuilder<Map>(
      future: futureData,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
         // Future is still loading
         if (!snapshot.hasData)
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
         else if (snapshot.data.isEmpty)
            return Container();
         else
            return Graph(snapshot.data);
      },
   );
}
```

For your `FutureBuilder` to work correctly you need to return a value in your `getData` and use the `snapshot` variable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I will try this and Accept it if it works for me.